# How to use Windows Azure Media Services encoded ism file to Smooth Stream in both iOS devices and Windows?

Tags: azure

I have a video called Spiderman.mp4 which I uploaded to Windows Azure Media Services using their Web UI (not console application). I also encoded the video into the preset "Playback for iOS and PC/MAC" using the Web UI. After I published, I get the URL As

http://azure-something.net/Spiderman.ism/Manifest

How do I Smooth Stream this Manifest file into both iOS and PC? I have used a Silverlight Smooth Streaming player for windows for this but it does not work for iOS.

Any help in this regard will be deeply appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the video file to Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) . Checkout https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services/#header-12

You seem to be converting the video file to IIS smooth streaming which justifies why it only works with Silverlight.

Comment: Are you able to play the live streaming file to ios ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the manifest file into the apple HLS (Http Live Streaming) content and you will be able to view it on ios.